# Enhance cucumber-jvm logging messages

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

In our e2e cucumber project in all classes that are under our control we use slf4j with logback for logging. Unfortunately standard cucumber logging leverages on java.util.logging [see here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/logging/LoggerFactory.java). We need to enhance log messages to e.g. add thread id to track paralel execution.

Although there is a [bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) that directs logs to slf4j, but even with this I didn't find a way to enhance log messages.

Is there a way to modify log messages produced by cucumber-jvm classes?

Comment: Your question lacks any sort of detail. So what you are saying right now is: "It tried to make it work but it doesn't work. How do I make it work". Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Tell me please what details are missing so that I can add them. To me it seemed clear: cucumber-jvm prints some logs and I want to modify them by adding some additional information. I really don't know how to be more specific despite reading the "how-to-ask" section.
Unfortunately I can't say where in cucumber-jvm source code are these messages printed. The one I have on mind are: step text printed after the step is executed and exception with stacktrace after test case fail.

Comment: The question you should answer is: "What would I have to do to see the things you see?" And you want to keep that list of things I'd have to do really small.

Comment: And if you are on a recent version of Cucumber, unless you've turned something on (like the `pretty` formatter) Cucumber won't log anything to standard out.